# Как поменять местами элементы ассоциативного массива в php?

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно поменять местами в массиве два элемента с произвольно заданными ключами. Например, есть массив

```
['b' => 0, 'a' => 1, 'c' => 2]
```

нужно сделать из него массив

```
['b' => 0, 'c' => 2, 'a' => 1]
```

(поменять местами значения с ключами `'a'` и `'c'`).

Comment: А что поменяется в результате этого? В чем идея?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, порядок обхода в foreach? Или php его не гарантирует?

Comment: да, поменяется порядок обхода для foreach.
Собственно элементы массива выводятся на экран и изначальный порядок оказался неправильным, а поменять я его не могу.

Comment: А как данные получаются? Из бд? Может проще на том уровне их поменять? А если данных больше и будет порядок у всех неправильный? Или гарантируется только три элемента массива, в которых два последних перепутаны?

Comment: самый простой способ добавить массив со значениями ключей в том порядке, в котором нужно обходить,  т.е. `$keys = ['b','c','a']`. Итерировать этот массив и обращаться к исходному по значению ключа.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну вот как раз и хотел узнать какова идея. Просто если будет только три элемента всегда, имхо даже цикл использовать не обязательно и достаточно вручника написать, а значит действо будет бессмысленно..... А если не три, а всегда разное количество, да еще разные могут быть перемешаны, то тут уже и подходы разные

Comment: Размер массива произвольный. ['b','a',c'] - просто пример.

Comment: @Oborotenby возникает резонный вопрос: как формируется массив и почему формируется криво и почему нельзя до этапа формирования его сделать как нужно? Может все же на том уровне подумать, нежели что-то непонятное делать?))

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/XaEs1f

```
<?php

$a = array('b' => 0, 'a' => 1, 'c' => 2);

print_r($a);

$keys = array_keys($a);

$i = array_search('a', $keys);
$j = array_search('c', $keys);

if ($i !== false && $j !== false) {
    $keys[$i] = 'c';
    $keys[$j] = 'a';
}

$b = array();

foreach ($keys as $key)
    $b[$key] = $a[$key];

print_r($b);
```

Понятия не имею, насколько это нормально, но вроде работает...

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('b' => 0, 'a' => 1, 'c' => 2);
$array_order = array('b', 'c', 'a');

$sorted_array = array_merge(array_flip($array_order), $array);
// или
$sorted_array = array_replace(array_flip($array_order), $array);
```

`array_flip` меняет местами ключи и значения
`array_merge` сливает массивы, с замещением на значения второго массива
`array_replace` замещает по ключам значения первого массива значениями второго

Взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array

Comment: А если мы не знаем изначальный порядок ключей  (т.е. $array_order у нас нет)? Знаем только, что нужно поменять 2 ключа местами.

Comment: @Oborotenby то есть у вас и массив разной длины может быть и вообще все элементы могут быть в разноброс, но при этом только два из них могут быть не на своих местах и именно поменяв их будет всё идеально? И почему поменяв только их, то не взирая на остальную рандомную последовательность результат будет удовлетворять? \*чешет репу*

Comment: @Oborotenby, согласна с Алексеем, возможно вы решаете проблему не с той стороны. Если у вас нет конкретного задания поменять рандомные элементы местами в массиве, а есть какой-то подтекст, то скорее всего проблему можно решить на этапе формирования массива